# Understanding of definition of a local martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, definition, martingales, local-martingales

In my lecture note, a local martingale is defined as the picture shows. I am a bit confused with the sequence of the stopping time. I understand this as every element in the sequence is a function which satisfies the definition of stopping time. Do I misunderstand this concept?

Definition of a local martingale:

[image]

Comment: You are correct, each $T_n$ is a stopping time.  Is that the only question you had about the concept?

Comment: Yes, thank you~  might need help in the future:)